# Windows 8 App Development - Is it possible to use System.Net.Sockets? (C#)

Tags: c#, networking, windows-8

As you may know, Microsoft removed the System.Net.Sockets namespace (of Visual C#) from Windows 8 apps (Visual Studio 2013), and replaced it with Windows.Networking.Sockets.

The new Windows.Networking.Sockets namespace is extremely hard and complicated to work with, and in my opinion the old System.Net.Sockets namespace is much better and easier for network programming.

Is it possible somehow to use the old System.Net.Sockets namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Portable Class Library and see whether the sockets API is more to your liking. Other than that, I don't think there is a way around Windows.Networking.Sockets.

Comment: Thanks, will try. Microsoft ruined a good language (C#) with their new whole Asynchronous idea. Instead of letting programmers decide if their methods are Synchronous or Asynchronous, they now FORCE the programmers to use Asynchronous methods. Programming is about freedom, not restricting the programmer to what the company thinks is the best thing for his app. You can't even do multi-threading any more on Windows 8 Apps development, you are now forced to use Async Tasks instead. Shame on Microsoft in this part... Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @BlueRay010 The new async pattern is actually quite nice once you wrap your head around it :)

Comment: Oh, do you prefer it over Multi-Threading? I mean, in C#, when I made a UDP server, I only made a while (true) loop with a Receive method, that Received and then processed packets. But now? I can't just do Receive in a while (true) loop (on a background thread), and keep receiving. I have to do many more lines of code... Do you regard it as easier than dealing with Multi-Threading and automatically receiving in a loop?

Comment: @BlueRay010 I have not specifically worked with sockets, yet, so I cannot comment on that.